# Making screen-readers read out <text> items in SVG graphics?

Tags: svg, accessibility, wai-aria, nvda

I've searched all over the place and not have any success with this.
I'm making SVGs like the following one in order to make them scalable, and also help people who are dyslexic so they can highlight the text and use plugins like Read Out Loud:

https://www.ole.bris.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/institution/TEL/TEL%20guides/Published%20TEL%20guides/Replay/record-now-instructions-web.svg

But I've not been able to get my copy of NVDA to read out the tab-indexed  fields as I tab through them. I've tried  fields and aria-label on various things...

Is there something simple I can change so NVDA (and similar screen readers) will read out the text as I tab through (NVDA does this on HTML pages).
Or should I just put the full description of all the text in my description at the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have `role="img"` in your svg root. That's borking everything, since it tells the accessibility API that it is just a single element, whose accessible name is always `aria-labelledby="svgTitle svgDesc"`

Try changing that to `role="graphics-document"` (or perhaps `role="application"` if you want fancier interactions) and I think you'll have a whole lot more luck.

Comment: YES! YES! YES! (a la Meg Ryan in When Harry Met Sally)! Thanks SO much! :-) I've been battling with this for ages, and I suspected there must "just" be a thing I could change to make it work. But I had no idea what the thing was or what to look for. A world of rich accessible guides awaits...! Thanks again. I want to do a little dance in the office!

Comment: Just curious, why isn't `graphics-document` (https://www.w3.org/TR/graphics-aria-1.0/#graphics-document) listed with all the other possible values of `role` in https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions ?

Comment: @slugolicious I think it's just an accident of history. Graphics-aria was developed separately from the rest of ARIA. However, I think it will be a mistake if future versions of wai-aria maintain this distinction. There are important gaps unaddressed by the separation of the specs. (In particular the notion of "operability" vs. "browsing" of data views). They should be merged IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to remove the `role` attribute from the `<svg>` element. It sounds counterintuative, but it should make any `<text>` elements accessible.

For an example, see tip 5 in this SitePoint article, which has great background and other helpful tips on making SVG more accessible in different use cases:
[Tips for Creating Accessible SVG](https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/)

From the above article:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="300" height="200" aria-labelledby="title desc">
<title id="title">Green rectangle</title>
<desc id="desc">A light green rectangle with rounded corners and a dark green border.</desc>
<rect width="75" height="50" rx="20" ry="20" fill="#90ee90" stroke="#228b22" stroke-fill="1" />
<text x="35" y="30" font-size="1em" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000">Website</text>
</svg>
```